# Unable to take user input to add the markers

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation

In the below code I'm unable to take user input to add marker of Lat and Longitude. It would be of great help if someone helps me in this problem

```
import pygmaps
mymap5 = pygmaps.maps(Lat, Long, Zoom)
a = float(input("Enter the lat of Person - 1 :"))
b = float(input("Enter the longitude Person - 1 :"))
mymap5.addpoint(a[0], b[0], "#ff0000", "Title")
mymap5.draw('pygmap.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to index a float, which is not supported. Try putting the following in your interpreter:

```
a = float(input("Enter the lat of Person - 1 :"))
b = float(input("Enter the longitude Person - 1 :"))

print(a, b)
```

In short, it looks like you just need to use `a` and `b` rather than `a[0]` and `b[0]`.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the edit from "slice" to "index"! I just tried `dis('[1,2,3][1]')`, `dis('[1,2,3].__getitem__(1)')`, and `dis('[1,2,3][1:2:1]')`; and `[1,2,3][1]` compiles with the fewest VM instructions. I guess I assumed grabbing a single index was a simple case of the built in slice function. Thanks for the learning opportunity!

Comment: Understand the confusion, especially since the notation used is so similar.

Comment: Possibly, but you should ask a new question rather than edit the existing question to be entirely different. It appears my answer helped you, please mark the answer as accepted and ask your new question in a different thread.

Comment: I tried adding the 4th parameter as a title to mymap5.addpoint but I'm getting error as follows: Exception has occurred: TypeError addpoint() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given.                                                                                                          mymap5.addpoint(a, b, "#ff0000", "Title")

Comment: You're passing arguments to the addpoint function which are not expected. You should consult pygmaps documentation and read what the addpoint function is expecting. From my online searches, it does not look like there is much support or documentation. In which case `import inspect` followed by `inspect.getfullargspec(mymap5.addpoint)` or similar should give clues about what addpoint is expecting as input. Consider asking this as a new question on SO, as you might find someone with pygmaps experience.